# How to insert a vpii in vector<vector<pair<int,int> > >

Tags: c++, vector, stl

How to insert a vector pair in `vector< vector < pair < int,int > > >`?

I am beginner of stl so please help me.

Comment: Having a `vector` of `vector` of `pair` is a sign of a bad design, you might want to reconsider it.

Comment: `std::map<int, int>` might be a good replacement for `vector<pair<int,int> >`.

Comment: You should try to describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: but i don't have any knowledge of map ....so i just use vector vector pair

Comment: i just designing a graph of edges with weight...

Comment: You can use std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, double>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *how to insert a vpii in `vector<vector<pair<int,int> > >`*:

```
vector<vector<pair< int,int> > > vvpii;
pair<int, int> pii(1, 2);
vector<pair<int, int> > vpii;
vpii.push_back(pii);
vvpii.push_back(vpii);

// or if your compiler supports c++11,
// you can use Brace-enclosed initializer lists
vvpii.push_back({ // vector initializer
    {1, 2}, // pair initializer
    {2, 3}, // another pair
});
```

Comment: You should mention that this is a C++11 solution, since the question is just tagged C++ and C++11 propagation is still in progress.

Comment: @JohnChadwick I added a comment to the relevant part